# Dirac Gamma matrix Algebra in different dimension

Tags: matrix

Do anyone know if we could do Dirac Gamma Matrix Algebra by FeynCalc with Gamma Matrices defined in different dimension than 4, e.g. DiracTrace of gamma matrices in 2+1 dimension?

Thanks!

Comment: In the [documentation](http://feyncalc.org/FeynCalcBook/) i see the command `Dimension`. So can't you set the `Dimension` to  'n' and then define your metric tensor and work with it.

Comment: Hi, to make it more specific. Say we have Dirac Gamma matrices in 2+1 d, which are just 2 by 2 Pauli Matrices. the trace of product of three gamma matrices should give me a Levi-Civita in that spacetime dimension. But I could not get the trace correct in FeynCalc.

Comment: Related: [Dirac Matrices in Higher Dimensions](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DiracMatricesInHigherDimensions/) (Wolfram Demo)

Answer (score 1):

Sure,
e.g.:

```
TR[DiracMatrix[mu,nu,rho,si,rho,nu,mu,si, Dimension -> n]]
```

gives

```
-4*(-2 + n)^3*n
```

Comment: Hi,What I mean is define gamma matrices in different dimensions, say in 2+1-d, gamma matrices are just Pauli Matrices, and trace of three gamma matrices should give you Levi-Civita \epsilon_{\mu \nu \sigma}. I do not know how it works. It seems like Levi-Civita are not available in (2+1)-d.